# What is Blüdhaven's status post New 52?

Tags: dc, batman, the-new-52, nightwing

In the New 52 era of DC Comics has the status of [Blüdhaven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bludhaven) been mentioned, either in conjunction with Nightwing or any other characters?  Before Flashpoint and the change over it was basically a toxic wasteland, but I'm wondering if that is still in place.

Comment: Unknown either way as far as I've seen.

Comment: When has Blüdhaven ever not been a toxic wasteland.

Comment: Touche @JackBNimble

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The New 52 has made no mention of Blüdhaven since its destruction by Chemo in the Final Crisis. There have been at least one [interview with the Nightwing writer, Kyle Higgins](http://www.ign.com/articles/2011/11/02/the-new-52-interviews-nightwing) who has moved Nightwing back to Gotham.

- Higgins mentions the company is focused on the future stories and directing writers to not be caught up in the past. Blüdhaven served its purpose, as a place for Nightwing to claim as his own and now DC is done with it, returning Nightwing to Gotham.
- Knowing DC, Blüdhaven will exist in a limbo until a writer decides he wants to bring it out of stasis and make whatever decisions need to be made at that time.
- For the record, in the previous continuity Blüdhaven no longer exists having been rendered a chemical wasteland using the villainous construct Chemo as a bomb.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is probably in limbo, like Fawcett City, etc, but I'd assume it exists for two reasons.

1. It is regularly referenced in DCs to major adaptations, Arrow and Young Justice.
2. All the other fictional cities still seem to exist in tact, including Opal and Dakota.

Answer (score 1):

Bludhaven does exist in the new 52 in batman vol 1 issue 1 or 2 nightwing talks about his time as a cop on the bludhaven beat

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Thanks for your answer but you will note there is already an accepted answer for this question.  We do appreciate your input though, but you may wish to look at our help section for formatting answers: we prefer having references for answers submitted.  Good luck on SFFSE!